# Can I apply for a Cuban visa without being a resident?

Tags: visas, cuba, residency

I would like to travel to Cuba and I need a tourist card (visa). Right now I am a visitor for a few weeks in the UK and I will not return to my residence (EU) country before travelling for Cuba.

Can I apply for a visa while I am in the UK, although it is not my residence country?

Comment: Before you buy a tourist card, check with your airline. On certain flights, the cost of the tourist card is included in the ticket price and you will get the application form at check-in or while in flight.

Comment: Whats your citizenship? I got mine in Mexico while in transit enroute to Cuba.  NZ Citizen.

Answer (score 3):

Many airlines sell tourist cards when you check in. Normally costs around 20 USD or so and gives you simple paper with 2 identical sides. At immigration they tear one of and keep other one is for you to keep until departure. Call airline and ask if they offer them on aircraft.

I was flying with Cayman Airways. They sold them at check in